# Converting strings to Core.Time.t from format string

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I have to to convert strings of the form `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S` to Time.t. Is there a Core equivalent of Calendar's `Printer.Time.from_fstring` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic version

As far as I know there is no such function in `Core` library. You can implement this easily using `scanf`:

```
open Core.Std

let of_parts d m y hr min sec =
  let time_of_day = Time.Ofday.create ~hr ~min ~sec () in
  let m = Month.of_int_exn m in
  let date = Date.create_exn ~y ~m ~d in
  Time.of_date_ofday date time_of_day ~zone:Time.Zone.utc

let strptime0 data =
  Scanf.sscanf data "%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d" of_parts
```

### Full version

The `strptime0` is a first approximation, that will parse input with a fixed format. It is not very hard to implement a true `strptime` function, that will accept format. To do this, we need to implement the following steps:

#### Transform format string

First of all we need to transform the format string from `strptime` language to format language, e.g., transform `%Y -> %4d`, etc, and then use `Scanf.format_from_string` to get the instance of `format` object. The return value of this function should be a format, suitable for scanf, and a permutation matrix, encoded as an array.

#### Rearrange arguments

You can use an array to specify the order of elements:

```
(** [rearrage f p a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5] call function [f] with
    provided arguments passed in the order specified by the
    permutation [p]

    The [i]th element of the permutation [p] specifies the subscript
    of the [i]'th argument to function [f]. Effectively [f] is called
    like this: $f a_{p[0]} ... a_{p[i]} ... a_{p[5]}$ *)

let rearrange f arr a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 =
  let args = [| a1; a2; a3; a4; a5; a6 |] in
  f args.(arr.(0)) args.(arr.(1)) args.(arr.(2))
    args.(arr.(3)) args.(arr.(4)) args.(arr.(5))
```

(this will work fine, if we will represent all parts with integers, once
    we will introduce floating point arguments (for `%S` we need to lift arguments into our own numbering type).

#### Glue together

So that finally, you will get something like this (you still need to fill in stubs)

```
(* d m y hr min sec *)
let canonical_format = format_of_string "%d%d%d%d%d%d"

(* this is a stub, that doesn't support rearrangment
   and works incorrectly for most of inputs *)
let fmt_of_time p = function
  | 'm' | 'Y' | 'H' | 'M' | 'S' -> 'd'
  | x -> x

let transform_format fmt =
  let p = Array.init 6 ~f:ident in (* stub: identity permutation *)
  let fmt = String.map fmt ~f:(fmt_of_time p) in
  let fmt = Scanf.format_from_string fmt canonical_format in
  p, fmt

let strptime data fmt =
  let (p,fmt) = transform_format fmt in
  let of_parts = rearrange of_parts p in
  Scanf.sscanf data fmt of_parts
```

So, as a result, we can do the following:

```
# strptime "09/05/1945 12:04:32" "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S";;
- : Core.Std.Time.t = 1945-05-09 08:04:32.000000-04:00
```